# Under what conditions does $\forall x(\alpha \to \beta) \leftrightarrow (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta)$ hold?

Tags: logic

It's a logical axiom that $\forall x(\alpha \to \beta) \to (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta)$. However, it's generally not true that $\forall x(\alpha \to \beta) \leftarrow (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta)$, except for some trivial case, say, $x$ doesn't occur free in either $\alpha$ or $\beta$.

What's the general condition that $\forall x(\alpha \to \beta) \leftrightarrow (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta)$ holds? What about $\exists x(\alpha \to \beta) \leftrightarrow (\exists x \alpha \to \exists x \beta)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any proof, but here is my intuition:

I doubt there is any general condition besides obvious

$$\forall x(\alpha \to \beta) \leftarrow (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta). \tag{1}$$

The problem is that it might be true for many different reasons, e.g. the universe being of size one or perhaps the $\forall x \beta$ is true and it makes the implication trivial. Observe that $\forall x(\alpha \to \beta)$ means that a single $x$ satisfying $\alpha$ is enough to make $\beta$ true (some clarification: it does *not* mean that $\beta$ is true in general, it is true only for that particular $x$). On the other hand $\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta$ means that you need $\alpha$ to hold for all the $x$es to satisfy $\beta$. For example, let's assume the universe has more than one element, then:

$$\forall x \Big(P(x) \to \exists y \big(P(x) \land P(y)\big)\Big)$$
would be of first kind (because you can set $y = x$), while
$$\forall x P(x) \to \forall x \exists y(P(x)\land P(y) \land x \neq y)$$

is the second kind, because you need to know, that there are at least two $x$es that satisfy $P$. So the general condition would be something like "from the $\forall x \alpha$ you need only one $x$ to make $\beta$ true", but that is exactly $(1)$.

I hope it explained something ;-)

Comment: To the observation that a single $x$ satisfying $\alpha$ makes $\beta$ true, note that nowhere (in the general case) it said that $x$ is not a free variable of $\beta$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't understand, in my first example $x \in FV(\beta)$. I am aware that this is not the same as $\exists x\alpha \to \forall x \beta$, do you think I should make it more clear?

Comment: I am referring to this, "Observe that $\forall x(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$ means that a single $x$ satisfying $\alpha$ is enough to make $\beta$ true." If $x$ is a free variable of $\beta$ then it doesn't meant that $\beta$ is *true*, just that some $x$ satisfies it. If for some other $x$, $\alpha$ is false it could just as well be that $\beta$ is not satisfied by that particular $x$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, I see. Well, I thought it was obvious, but since it is not, I added some clarification. Thank you for pointing that out!